# Can't change size of recorded video with WebRTC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc

I am a trainee JavaScript and I have just recently started using TypeScript, so maybe this is a silly question but I cant figure it out. I am working on this system for answering questions via video integrating WebRTC. I have two video tags, one for the video that is being recorded and the other one for playing the already recorded video. How can I change the size of the second one? I didn't find an options parameter so I am clueless.

```
const playRecorded = () => {
    console.log(recordedBlobs.current);
    let superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs.current[videoUp.id], {
      type: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus',
    });
    if (recordedVideo.current !== null) {
      recordedVideo.current.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
      recordedVideo.current.controls = true;
      (recordedVideo as any).current.play();
    } else {
      console.error('la cagué');
    }
  };
```